# Divisible by Zero Exception

Tags: c#

I am doing some calculations for loan schedule payment for an employee and I keep getting

> ClassName: "System.DivideByZeroException", Message: "Attempted to divide by zero."

I don't know what I'm doing wrong,maybe I am not casting the decimals well.

```
private static decimal ReturnPayments(decimal loanAmount, int durationMonths, decimal interestMonthly)
{
   return (loanAmount * interestMonthly)/ (decimal) (1-Math.Pow((int)(1 
                                                                      + interestMonthly), -durationMonths));
}
public IEnumerable<LoanRepaymentSchedule> GetRepayment(string employeeId, decimal principalAmt, decimal rate, int terms)
{
   var employee = _employeeService.FindByAsync(e => e.Id == employeeId 
                                                    && e.Status == EntityStatus.Active).Result;
   var results = employee.FirstOrDefault();
   var currentBalance = principalAmt - 0;
   decimal monthlyRate = rate / 1200;
   var monthlyPaymentAmt = ReturnPayments(currentBalance, terms, monthlyRate);
   var result = new List<LoanRepaymentSchedule>();
   for (var currentPayment =1; currentPayment<= terms; currentPayment++)
   {
      decimal interestAmount = currentBalance * monthlyRate;
      decimal deductedBalance = monthlyPaymentAmt - interestAmount;
      currentBalance = currentBalance - deductedBalance;

      var monthlyDetail = new LoanRepaymentSchedule
         {

            Balance = currentBalance,
            PrincipalAmt = deductedBalance,
            InterestAmt = interestAmount,
            TotalAmt =monthlyPaymentAmt,
            EmployeeId = results.Id

         };

      result.Add(monthlyDetail);

   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: As the error suggests, you've some value becoming zero. Just debug at the places where you're doing divisions..

Comment: What is the result of `1 + interestMonthly`?

Comment: the only place in above code a divide by zero can happen in when `durationMonths` is 0 or `interestMonthly` is 0 and `durationMonths` is anything

Comment: The guy upstairs already said

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that your problem lies here:

```
return (loanAmount * interestMonthly) / (decimal)(1 - Math.Pow((int)(1 + interestMonthly), -durationMonths));
```

Specifically, here:

```
(int)(1 + interestMonthly)
```

Assuming `interestMonthly` is a value like 0.05 (i.e. 5%), let's do the calculation:

```
1 + interestMonthly = 1.05
(int)(1.05) = 1
```

In the scope of the rest of your method, you'll effectively do `Math.Pow(1, -durationMonths)`, which will give you `1`, and then perform `1 - 1`, which will give you 0. Finally you divide by this 0 and get the exception.

Reason for your problem: Integers cannot store fractions, so casting to an integer basically disregards the non-integer component of the value. You should probably change this from `(int)` to `(double)` to use with the `Math.Pow()` method:

```
return (loanAmount * interestMonthly) / (decimal)(1 - Math.Pow((double)(1 + interestMonthly), -durationMonths));
```